# ReactRouter V6.17 not showing pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to see the home and product page content when I load browser, but when I load the browser, it displays nothing. It's not clear to me what the issue or problem is.

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Header from './components/Header'
import Footer from './components/Footer'
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen'
import ProductScreen from './screens/ProductScreen'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <main clasName='py-3'>
        <Container>
          <Route path="/" element={<HomeScreen />} exact />
          <Route path="/product/:id" element={<ProductScreen />} />
        </Container>
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All `Route` components must be rendered by a `Routes` component directly, or another `Route` component in the case of nested routes.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes, // <-- import Routes component
  Route
} from 'react-router-dom';
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import ProductScreen from './screens/ProductScreen';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <main clasName='py-3'>
        <Container>
          <Routes> // <-- wrap routes
            <Route path="/" element={<HomeScreen />} />
            <Route path="/product/:id" element={<ProductScreen />} />   
          </Routes>
        </Container>
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```